# Allowing elements to repeat only if they are in different languages, in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, internationalization, xsd

If an element is restricted to occur only once, can you still have it occur in multiple languages, if you're using the global `xml:lang` attribute?

On one hand, I'd understand if you can't. On the other, it's really the same piece of information, just in a different language. So being able to have the element multiple times, if the lang attribute is different, would be helpful.

Otherwise you have to set it to `unbounded`, which isn't really what I want. Is there a solution for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to allow elements to repeat if and only if they have different values for xml:lang would be:

1. In the content model for the parent element (call it P), allow the child to repeat:

   ```
   <xsd:complexType name="parent">
     <xsd:sequence>
       ...
       <xsl:element ref="tns:C" 
         minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
       ...
     </
   </
   ```
2. In the element declaration for P, impose a uniqueness constraint on tns:C/@xml:lang.

   ```
   <xsd:element name="P" type="tns:parent">
     <xsd:unique name="unique-lang-for-C">
       <xsd:selector xpath="tns:C"/>
       <xsd:field xpath="@xml:lang"/>
     </
   </
   ```

End result: you can have multiple C elements, as long as they have distinct values for xml:lang.

If your heart is set on referring to C with maxOccurs="1", then a simple way to allow multiple languages is to make C be a wrapper for language-specific information:

```
<C>
  <en>Hi, mom.</en>
  <fr>Bonjour, maman!</fr>
  <es>¡Hola, mamacita!</es>
</C>
```

Comment: I like the former better, it lets me use the `lang()` function. Thanks. The more strict way would be to use `xsd:key`?

Comment: Yes, I believe xsd:key may count as more strict:  it would require C elements to have xml:lang values.